# Worker Role Importance in Windows Azure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, azure

In my cloud application am using only one role i.e web role not using worker role.i have little bit confusion between web role and worker role .

1)Both are same or not?

2)In our application what is the importance of worker role?

3)If i want  to add worker role in my cloud application then how can add to my application.Please suggest me?

Thanks in Advance,

PCSSCP.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find this answered in several places, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11579428/272109). They're both Windows servers, but Web Roles have IIS enabled. You can do the same things in Web and Worker roles. If, say, you're using Tomcat for a web server, it's better to use a Worker role since you don't need IIS.

You go with separate roles when you have different scaling needs. For example, maybe you want a Small (single-core) Web role for your website, running 2-5 instances depending on traffic. Then maybe a Medium (2-core) Worker with 2-10 instances depending on job workload in your Azure queue. Just a made-up scenario, but hopefully that illustrates why you might want multiple roles defined. You're free to run all your code in a single role

Comment: Hi David,Thanks for your explanation.But my problem is my application is performance is not good. previously(before deployed in azure) this same application performance is very good.but now it's to slow.

Comment: @PCSSCP: You have to profile your application and find out why teh performance is no longer good.